# How to use seo friendly URLs in a custom controller in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have a custom module defined in a Prestashop 1.7.1.1 installation.

This module defines a new category page adding custom functionality and layouts.

Category `1034` represents `Foo Brand` and can be accessed both by:

https://www.example.com/module/categorypage/subcategory?id_category=1034

and its seo friendly URL:

https://www.example.com/1034-foo-brand

However, when the latest is used the displayed page is the first one.

While debugging in the browser I can see how Prestashop is returning a html 302 code hence redirecting to the non seo friendly URL.

This is the init function for the controller. But I can not further continue or investigate on what shall I do/look for to enable the usage of seo friendly URLs for this overrided page/controler:

1. *Shall the return of seo friendly URLs be incorporated in the controller?*
2. *If so, where and how?*

```php
public function init()
{

    // Get category ID
    $id_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_category');
    if (!$id_category || !Validate::isUnsignedId($id_category)) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Missing category ID');
    }

    $checkCategoryDepth = new Category($id_category, $this->context->language->id);

    $depth = $checkCategoryDepth->level_depth - 1;

    if ($depth > 2) {
        Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getCategoryLink($checkCategoryDepth->id, $checkCategoryDepth->link_rewrite));
    }

    if ($depth == 2) {
        $this->context->smarty->assign('selected_category_id', $checkCategoryDepth->id);
        $this->category = new Category($checkCategoryDepth->id_parent, $this->context->language->id);
    } else {
        $this->category = $checkCategoryDepth;
    }

    parent::init();

    // Check if the category is active and return 404 error if is disable.
    if (!$this->category->active) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    }

    // Check if category can be accessible by current customer and return 403 if not
    if (!$this->category->checkAccess($this->context->customer->id)) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have access to this category.');
        $this->customer_access = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that friendly URL is redirected to non-friendly URL?

Comment: @idnovate Yes I mean that

Answer (score 2):

If you use your own module with a new page which has its own controller you should define friendly URL rules in your module's main class within a hook moduleRoutes. So, at first register your module in this hook within install method

```
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('moduleRoutes');
}
```

then determine how your URL will be built

```
public function hookModuleRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'module-your_module-your_controller'  => array(
            'controller' => 'your_controller',
            'rule'       => 'some_short_url_you_want_to_have', // for example category/{id_category}/{rewrite}
            'keywords'   => array(
                'id_category' => array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_category'),
                'rewrite'            => array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*')
            ), // here should be described everything what is used for rule
            'params'     => array(
                'fc'     => 'module',
                'module' => 'your_module',
            )
        )
    );
}
```

and after these manipulations you should have your URLs working.

Comment: Thanks I am going through your answer and trying it.